# Asp.net core no update when I am trying to change something

Tags: asp.net, angular

When I am trying to change something in the html code generated by default by Visual, nothing change.

I can not see my changes when I rebuilt. If I change something, the website stay the same than the beginning, ignoring changes

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @JunKang when I built the project, all my changes are not updated

Comment: @JunKang It is better ?

Comment: @PierreWhatsUpScadra Do you have NodeJs installed on your machine?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0#installation

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes I have it ...

Comment: @PierreWhatsUpScadra! With your website open in chrome browser open developer tools (press F12) and then switch to Network tab. Now make some changes in any home.component.html file and save in Visual Studio. Check if you see any activity under network tab or any console error?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood no activity in the network and this error : Error handling response: Error: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '::content .topArtAd, ::content .vce_adsense_expand, ::content .widget_ad_300x250_btf, ::content .youtubeSuperLeaderOverallAdArea, ::content a[href^="http://hd-plugins.com/download/"]

Answer (score 0):

Check this article and ensure that you have all pre-requisites installed 
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1432/aspnet-core-apps-using-angular-cli-template

- Visual Studio 2017
- .NET core 2.0 or above
- Node.js
- Angular CLI: To be installed as a global npm package using the following command

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Nothing has change I installed : Visual Studio 2017, .Net core 2.0 and Node.js 10.2, angular/cli too but nothing has changed. When I generated a new project too